# Is there a way to accept only specific datatype like date with contenteditable html attribute?

Tags: html, contenteditable

Is there a way to achieve something like this?

```
<pre>
<p contenteditable="true" type="date">12-04-1994</p>
</pre>
```

so it only accepts date formats?

Comment: You mean like `<input type="date"/>` in HTML5

Comment: no, it is not an input, I have to use it with contenteditable tag since its editable property is dynamic and may change to false.

Comment: You can achieve this by appying some contraint on accepting the string.

Comment: If you don't want all the features (and problems) of contentEditable, then you should really go for an input and for example change its "disabled" attribute. ContentEditable is a huge can of worms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help; note that it ignores everything after the 10th character and it doesn't check the actual date values for validity (e.g. you can say 45/96/2543 and it will be valid).

```js
setInterval(check,100);
function check(){
  var date=document.getElementById("date").innerHTML;
  if(!isNaN(parseInt(date.charAt(0), 10))&&!isNaN(parseInt(date.charAt(1), 10))&&date.charAt(2)=="-"&&date.charAt(5)=="-"&&!isNaN(parseInt(date.charAt(3), 10))&&!isNaN(parseInt(date.charAt(4), 10))&&!isNaN(parseInt(date.charAt(6), 10))&&!isNaN(parseInt(date.charAt(7), 10))&&!isNaN(parseInt(date.charAt(8), 10))&&!isNaN(parseInt(date.charAt(9), 10))){
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="Yes Date";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="No Date";
  }
}
```

```html
<pre>
<p contenteditable='true' id='date' style='border:1px solid black;'>Edit me</p>
<p id='output'></p>
</pre>
```

Comment: I want the date dialog box to pop out like it does in <input type="date"/>, is that possible?

Comment: You could make an invisibly-outlined input and put it inside your `p` element.